# Find Span(S) if S = {(x,y) y >= x>= 0}

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V = R^2

Find Span(S) if S = {(x,y) y is greater than or equal to x is greater than or equal to  0}

I'm not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $(1,2)$ and $(1,3)$ belong to $S$. By definition $(1,3)-(1,2)=(0,1)\in\text{Span}(S)$. Then $(1,0)=(1,2)-2(0,1)\in \text{Span}(S)$ as well. Hence $\mathbb{R}^2=\text{Span}(\left\{(1,0),(0,1)\right\}\subset \text{Span}(S)$. It follows that $\text{Span}(S)=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Even shorter, notice that  $(1,2)$ and $(1,3)$ belong to $S$ and are linearly independent. Hence they generate a subspace of dimension $2$ but $\mathbb{R}^2$ has dimension $2$, so this subspace has to be everything.

Or if you want to do this explicitly, simply take a general element $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and write $(a,b)$ as a (finite) linear combination of elements belonging to $S$.